# Save .xlsx files via excel vba, without opening saved file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making excel vba code that makes outlook message and attach excel file itself(xlsx) for the message

below line is from my code.

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Date & " " & "Position Report Ver.2.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

This code saves xlsx file to specific folder.

I want just saving copied xlsx file.

but my code automatically opens saved file(xlsx file.) right after saving. and original file is closed.

macro should run even after generating xlsx files because it should be attached to outlook message by vba macro.

but, because xlsx file is opened right after saving, I can't run vba code after saving.

How can I save from xlsm to xlsx without opening?

I searched stackoverflow but I can't find the solution. code won't work or can't save to xlsx(just xlsm copy)... I couldn't find perfect answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please give this a try...

Remember to check the filename as I used the Format function to remove the invalid character from the filename.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy") & " " & "Position Report Ver.2.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: But... How Does it work?

this code just copied sheet and don't contain code that reopens xlsm file.

but xlsm file automatically reopens with this code. I really wonder how it works..

Comment: The line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy` adds a new workbook with all the sheets from the Macro workbook and then SaveAs command saves the new workbook with .xlsx extension and closes it. So in the end, you see your macro workbook again. I think that's what you were trying to achieve. If that takes care of your original question, please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Comment: is my question marked as solved? sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, and your answer is very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@sktneer, this worked better. ThisWorkbook did not copy the sheets with data, but only opened a blank workbook. But ActiveWorkbook did the job.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy") & " 
" & "Position Report Ver.2.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: @Umair You are talking something strange. :)